# How to place 2 node fileds in the same row at back-end node edit page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, field

I created new content type and it has 2 new fields (one is input, other select - drop-down), semantically related one to other. So I want to position them in the same row on node edit page. I tried to use groups to achieve that, but anything I've tried does not give me what I want. Tried "Horizontal tab" group with 2 fields in it. Tried 2 "Horizontal tab" groups next to each other with one field in each. Nothing helps.

Is it possible at all and if yes how to place 2 fields in the same row on node edit (back-end with standard back-end theme) page?

I would prefer to avoid CSS tweaks of admin theme. Hopefully those field groups could do the job, with some specific settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
@MilanG As you are using field_group module already what you can do is, create a div field_group add your desired fields to it and give that field group class container-inline which will show those two fields inline. Just tried it on my local drupal 7 site and works perfect!

Comment: Yes, but that seems like too much work. Too bad those field groups can't achieve such a basic request.

Comment: LOL, you download and use a CMS for free yet still complain. Search `drupal 7 theme node form` on google for the correct way to do it, which is to create your own template and add the template suggestion in a preprocess hook.

Comment: Did you try to alter form and add prefix on your first field and suffix to your second field , to create a div wrapper with native class for online label etc.. ? @MilanG

Comment: No. I'm sure something like this could be done, but I was searching for some easier to achieve solution. Without coding, hoping field grouping could give me that.

Comment: @MilanG As you are using field_group module already what you can do is, create a div field_group add your desired fields to it and give that field group class `container-inline` which will show those two fields inline. Just tried it on my local drupal 7 site and works perfect!

Comment: Yes! That's the answer I was looking for. Add it as an real answer and I'll mark it as correct one.